# Passing variable to constructor to a derived class gives garbage value, both the base and derived class's constructors have different parameters. Why?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, garbage

The derived and base class's constructor both have different parameters.

When passing a variable to the constructor of the derived class, it is giving garbage value when declaring an array of base class. Array size is not 'n' but some garbage value.

```
class LinkedList{
public:
    Node* head;
    LinkedList()
    {
        cout << "c";
        head=NULL;          
    }
};
class hashing : public LinkedList{
public:
    int n;
    hashing(int num)
    {
        this->n=num;
    }
    LinkedList* l = new LinkedList[n];
    void iterateL()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
             l[i].head=NULL;
             cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
};
int main() 
{
int n=7;
hashing op(n);
}
```

The loop inside hashing class is expected to run 7 times but after running 4 times it gives an error.

Comment: Even I tried putting a function and passing 'n' to that function. Still it gives an error. I think initialization of array of class LinkedList is posing some problem but I can not figure out what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the problem is subtle here (to the point where I didn't see the issue at first).

The problem is you're initializing using the value of n (`this->n`) during the in class member initialization.

The problem is, in C++, those initializers are all run during member initialization, which is prior to the constructor body. Since you don't set the value of `this->n` until the constructor body, `this->n` isn't initialized at all

In other words, what you have is the same as writing

```
hasing(int num): l(new LinkedList[n]) {
   this->n = num;
}
```

This occurs because by default, all members are initialized in the order specified in the class, substituting default member initializers (the expression after the `=` in the class definition) as appropriate.

There are several solutions:

**Using the member initializer**

```
hashing(int num): n(num),l(new LinkedList[n])
{

}
```

**Using the constructor body:**

```
hashing(int num)
{
   this->n = num;
   this->l = new LinkedList[n];
}
```

In both of the above cases, I would not set the default member specifier.  I would just declare the pointer.

```
LinkedList* l; // No default member initializer
```

Finally, I would make sure you properly handle destruction, and copy/move assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Your `hashing` constructor should look like this:

```
hashing(int num)
{
   this->n=num;
   l = new LinkedList[n];   // allocate once 'n' is known
}
```

otherwise, you are not allocating enough elements in `l`. In fact, you are allocating `n` elements, but since `n` is not given a default value, it is garbage, and UB to use.

The default value for `l` can just be:

```
LinkedList* l = nullptr;
```

Of course, make sure to delete the memory in the destructor:

```
~hashing() 
{
  delete [] l;
}
```

Comment: What difference does it makes allocating LinkedList* l OUTSIDE the constructor or INSIDE it? I did not get it quite well. Thanks it did solve my problem.

Comment: The constructor is the *entry point* for an object. If you don't initialize things in the constructor, they won't get initialized at all.

Answer (score 1):

When the body of a constructor gets control all non-static members of the class are already constructed.

So this data member

```
LinkedList* l = new LinkedList[n];
```

was already constructed using an indeterminate value of the data member n.

Rewrite the constructor the following way

```
hashing(int num) : n( num )
{
}
```

Pay attention to that there is no sense to declare the class hashing as a derived class of LinkedList because simultaneously you are also using the composition